# C: save values from a text file to a memory field

Tags: c, file-io, text-files, scanf

I am trying to open a text file and save the float values to a specific memory-address to work with them in an assembly-program. 
My problem is that I have a restriction to the format of the values in the text file:

```
if(sscanf(line,"%f  mm  %f  mm", 
  &data1[linesread], &data2[linesread]) != 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in line: %s\n",line);
    fprintf(stderr, "Aborted.");
    break;
}
```

What does `%f mm %f mm` in `sscanf()` stand for?

`%f` means that the first and the second value of the line have to be a float-value but I don't understand what "mm" means.

When I try to read in a line formatted like this:

```
5.0 2.0
```

I always get:

```
Read: 5.0 2.0
Error in line: 5.0 2.0

Aborted.
```

Comment: The input string should like like: `42.0  mm  23.4  mm` (with two spaces between each value/unit).

Comment: The number of spaces doesn't matter, but the `mm` should of course be there.

Comment: Note that with the code as written, you will never spot whether the second `mm` is absent, but the first `mm` must be present.  Since the white space in the format string means 'optional white space' in the data string, a valid input string for that format could be `999mm9` or `99.9 mm 10.10 mm` or even `99.999999999999999999999999999999E-99 mm 0xA4P-9 Zanzibar` (the second numeric string is a hexadecimal floating point value, equivalent to `0.3203125` — as will be intuitively obvious to everyone; OK — I cheated and wrote a program to find out what the value was).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
if(sscanf(line, "%f %f", &data1p[linesread], &data2[linesread]) != 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both your code and the input file need to agree if the mm's should be present.

As Jurica says, remove the two mm's from your code. Alternatively, you could try Paul's suggestion of adding the two mm's in your input file. The correct solution for you depends upon the format restrictions of your input file.

My guess is that mm means millimeters, which is probably the units of your data.